# Remove all zeroes from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples in python :

Example :

```
lstA = [ (12,0,20,50), (30,70,80,15), (11,12,0,35), (7,6,5,4), (1,0,0,4) ]
```

I want as output in the original list tuples with the zero values removed.
So for the above input , the output should be :

```
lstA = [(12,20,50), (30,70,80,15), (11,12,35), (7,6,5,4), (1,4)]
```

How to do this in a pythonic way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass these through a list compression and make new tuples as you go:

```
lstA = [ (12,0,20,50), (30,70,80,15), (11,12,0,35), (7,6,5,4), (1,0,0,4) ]

cleaned = [tuple(n for n in sublist if n != 0) for sublist in lstA]

# [(12, 20, 50), (30, 70, 80, 15), (11, 12, 35), (7, 6, 5, 4), (1, 4)]
```

Comment: thanks! that answers what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with `filter` and `lambda` from other programming languages you might prefer something like this even though it is not as pythonic:

```
>>> original_tuples = [(12, 0, 20, 50), (30, 70, 80, 15), (11, 12, 0, 35), (7, 6, 5, 4), (1, 0, 0, 4)]
>>> tuples_without_zero = [tuple(filter(lambda x: x != 0, t)) for t in original_tuples]
>>> tuples_without_zero
[(12, 20, 50), (30, 70, 80, 15), (11, 12, 35), (7, 6, 5, 4), (1, 4)]
```